# Running a java application on a web server as a web application?

Tags: java, web-applications

I have a program in JavaSE which is the server side of a file upload/download application. Now I want to deploy and make it work on a CentOS VPS. I could simulate the client/server connection on my own computer but I don't know how to make it work on a server as a web application. It will let the client to upload and download files and also view their own files.(database operations I think)

Which technology can I use for it for a JavaSE application?

Comment: what protocol are you using between the client and the server to upload file  ?

Comment: I am using http for it. I am also confused about that FTP or HTTP.

Answer (score 1):

It is possible to run java code via JSP (Java Server Pages). This can be a great option for running your app on the web (if it is a small app). [Here's a short tutorial](http://www.java-tips.org/java-ee-tips/javaserver-pages/how-to-run-java-code-in-a-jsp-page-2.html)

If your code is more complex, I suggest you build it around a framework, e.g. [Play! Framework](http://www.playframework.org/)

**--EDIT--**

JSP is a bit like PHP or a web templating language like Mako for Python.

You can embed tags that actual contain java code. This java code can do powerful things, it can actually be the code that you use to up/download files. As long as it doesn't contain complex OOP and the like, you can use it right in JSP.

To start off, you need the [JSP environment](http://jsp.davidcastro.com/setupenvironmenttutorial.jsp) running on your server.

Then on your web page, in between the `<% %>`  tags, right in the java code that will up/download files.

e.g.

```
<%

void dldFile(String fName){
    //code to download file...
}
%>

<form>
<!--get user input-->
</form>

<% dldFile (userInputString); %>
```

Comment: It could be as simple as upload & download. What do I have to use to make work the JSPs?

Comment: You have to set up the JSP environment... http://jsp.davidcastro.com/setupenvironmenttutorial.jsp

Answer (score 1):

You probably would have to rewrite a lot of code to make the switch from JavaSE to a web app.

The cool kid in Java these days seems to be [Play](http://www.playframework.org/)

A [simple File Upload](http://www.playframework.org/documentation/1.0/5things#a5.Straightforwardfileuploadmanagementa)  in Play is shown in their documentation.

Link to [Play tutorials](http://www.playframework.org/documentation/1.2.2/home)

Comment: Play has superb documentation and after running through the tutorial I am convinced you can finish the file upload in a few hours.